# How to make a Rule String which states if another String is allowed returning a Boolean

Tags: c#

I have run into an interesting problem, I already have 2 working solutions however 1 of them is incredibly slow, and the other is incredibly limited.
I'm trying to brainstorm ideas on how to solve this problem Efficiently while also being as flexible as possible. I was hoping someone may have some ideas on how to go about this since I'm completely stumped.

I have a name, let's say I have some strings: "A" "B" "C" "TEST" and so on.

Then I have another string let's say... "(A OR TEST) AND B NOT C" or something along that line.

Now I need to make a Function where I can feed the second string alongside one of the first, and return a Boolean.

So:

```
Function(InputString, RulesString)
    return RulesString Allows InputString

Call Function("C", "A OR TEST OR B NOT C") - Would return False as the RuleString doesn't allow C

Call Function("A", "A OR TEST OR B NOT C") - Would return True as A is allowed alongside TEST and B
```

The challenge is performance, I need something that's as efficient as possible since this is being called VERY often.

My first, super cheap easy solution was a Hashset
And doing

```
Function(InputString, Hashset)
    return Hashset.contains(InputString)
```

Obviously, this doesn't solve the issue, it's performant and does the basic idea. However, I need more flexibility than that.

My second solution was significantly more complicated and took up roughly 20% of CPU Usage.
But did cover all the cases I needed however it was TOO complicated and too costly.

As a Side note, I'm using c#.

Comment: "I need something that's as efficient as possible" - I doubt that's really the case. At some point, I'm sure you'd stop and say "I don't need to optimize this any further, it meets my needs." So do you have concrete performance requirements, and a benchmark to test any candidate code against? Sharing that would be useful. I'd expect a general approach of writing something that converts a rule string into some kind of predicate, and a cache of those predicates, so that you don't need to do the rule parsing multiple times.

Comment: _"My first, super cheap easy solution was a Hashset"_ So, the second argument does _not_ have to be a string?

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, this is something I'm calling possibly Thousands of times a Frame in a game where I need to maintain 60-120 fps ideally. Now I don't expect to always be able to reach that, however, if I can squeeze more performance out then I will. There's no real benchmarking or anything atm, it just needs to be fast. Ideally Very fast.

Comment: @41686d6564 While it doesn't HAVE to be a string, it's very much ideal since the Rules change dynamically according to values inputted by the user/player. So a string is simple and fast to iterate to see the results, this is used in a kind of simulation game.

Comment: What does your grammar look like. I find `(A OR TEST) AND B NOT C` hard to parse in my head, particularly since the input you are checking takes only a single input (in your examples `C` and `A`). Consider pre-parsing the rule (likely into a tree) as soon as the user creates it. When you want to test a variable, first check to see if it's an acceptable token, and then walk the rule tree to see what happens

Comment: @Flydog57 Sorry fixed the Examples. I originally wrote it as something else but decided to simplify it, I failed to actually verify it after I simplified it making it more complicated.
That's an interesting idea, How exactly would a tree like this work though? There are no like "Children" rules? so I can't really see how you could handle this in a tree fashion?

Comment: Is `NOT` a binary operator in your grammar? Most of the time `NOT` is unary when doing boolean arithmetic. I still don't understand `A OR TEST OR B NOT C` and particularly how you evaluate it with a string like `"C"` or `"A"`. Do you mean it's true if the input is A or TEST or B, and false if it's C. What happens if the input is E or QQQ

Comment: E and QQQ and any other value aren't in the Ruleset, so it wouldn't be allowed.
This is used to support TAGS of individual things, said tags can also be parents/children to other tags.

So by saying "Not C" I'm specifically saying NO to all C's except if it's A, B, or TEST.
And if I don't specify something that is Allowed, then everything is allowed. But thats not the case for things I don't allow.

There's more going on but that's the rough idea of how I'm using this.

This grammar in general though "A OR B OR TEST NOT C" is just an example of how the RuleString may look.

Comment: @NuclearWolf: _"So a string is simple and fast to iterate to see the results"_ A string is **by no means** the fastest or most efficient approach here. The only benefit is that it's easier to read by you, but not by the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line: `Call Function("A", "(A OR TEST) AND B NOT C)")` would return *false* because it does not satisfy "AND B". "A B" or "TEST B" would return true. Perhaps I have it wrong?

A first step I'd consider would be a simple good/bad filter. Parse the expression and determine the good/bad inputs as two hashsets. E.g. `(A OR TEST) AND B NOT C`
could parse out as bad=("C"), good=("A","B","TEST). Easy to check input against the two hashsets [assuming any input not in either hashset is implicitly disallowed].

If you're using a rule string more than once, I'd add a hash-to-parse lookup and re-use the parse rather than re-calculate each time.

It gets harder when you have to deal with required pairs. E.g. `(A OR TEST) AND B NOT C` means to me that `A B` and `TEST B` are valid, not "A", "TEST" or "C" or "D". If you expand your parse process to actually calculate the logic, the "good/bad" sets become valid input strings, e.g. bad=("C"), good=("A B","TEST B").

For `"(A AND B) OR (C AND D)"`: `"A B"`,`"C D"` are valid but nothing else.

Comment: Yea sorry, I fixed the code examples to "A OR TEST OR B NOT C" instead. I did actually make a mistake there haha sorry.

Yea right now that seems to be the best route, parsing the RuleString and creating an Allowed and NotAllowed hashset from the Rulestring and checking those.